# Android complex Player layout design

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to convert the following image into a layout,

[image]

If you look closely the bottom and top view behind the **Play** button are separated and the **Play** button needs to be fitted in between them.

Here's the top holder,
[image]

and the bottom holder,
[image]

Here's what I've done so far,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_blur"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="162dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topHolderLayout"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/middle_separator"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/top_holder_top_part"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/middle_separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"></View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomHolderLayout"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/middle_separator"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/top_holder_bottom_part"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Since it's solely depends on the pixels so doesn't works on different screen sizes. What would be the best way to adopt this type of design? Any kind of help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What a mess! Layouts aren't your point of strength, I guess... You should: **1** Flatten your design (a single RelativeLayout and no child layout inside is ore than enough and ensures better performances). **2** you don't need 2 separate lines - a single **9 patch** will do - just overlay the big button on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your layout to scale with device screen, you may do one of the following:

1. Create separate images for each screen density (this may be a good idea in case of your buttons):

   > ```
   > res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
   > res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
   > res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
   > res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
   > ```
   >
   > **Source:** http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
2. Create a drawable XML resource in res/drawable.

For example, background of your top holder might look like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#e0e0e0" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="128dp"
        android:topRightRadius="128dp" />
</shape>
```

And bottom holder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#e0e0e0" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="128dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="128dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Your buttons may then overlay the holders (you don't need to "cut" round holes in them).

3. Create a 9-patch image using *draw9patch* tool from Android SDK, as described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html